# How to duplicate ACP Pro settings in a different hosted WP?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields Pro on a WordPress site. In order to make the site a sandbox playground environment for our client, I am duplicating the site in a different instance so their changes won't break our site. However, when I duplicated the site, the ACF Pro settings and the custom fields did not transfer over to the new site.

1) Where are the settings saved for the ACF Pro fields we created?
2) How can I duplicate the settings from the old site to the new site without having to manually recreate the same settings by hand?

Comment: Export field groups from `Custom Fields >> Tools >> Export` and import on your development site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Development flow - Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400955/development-flow-wordpress-advanced-custom-fields)